# Does writing program using global variables is safer?

Tags: c++, c, overflow

I was reading about buffer, stack and heap overflows. I read this [post](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/A-Heap-of-Risk-747161.html) as well. my question is like that: if I use only global variables in my code, can I say it prevents all the exploits of overflow?

let's say I have this buffers in code declared in the global scope:

```
char buf1[10];
char buf2[100];
```

If I send `buf1` as the buffer to `recv(int s, char *buf, int len,int flags);`

1. I will overwrite the data segment and may ruin the `buf2` content, right?
2. Would I be able to run a code from it because as I know it is not a code segment and data segment is not executable.

Can we conclude that using Globals is the safest way?

Comment: The safest way is _not to overrun your buffers_.

Comment: IMO, this is roughly equivalent to committing suicide when you're 25 to ensure against dying of cancer when you get old.

Comment: As long as you pass the right value for `len`, you won't overflow your buffer at all. *This is not a difficult concept*.

Comment: Some good insight here:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135697/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-make-c-less-prone-to-buffer-overflows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where your data is.  If you try hard enough, you can write outside it.  Whether or no any stack buffer overrun might be used to overwrite a return address and cause code in the buffer to be executed, that is architecture dependent.  IMHO, data in the stack segment should not be executable and and attempt to execute it should result in a memory-management interrupt.

Using 'globals' instead of stack variables is anyway not a sane solution for anything except trivial apps.

I only ever load data into dynamicaly-allocated buffers inside buffer classes, so stack buffer overruns have never been a problem in my apps, (and besides, I just don't overrun buffers!).

Answer (score 7):

No, not at all.  Whilst its harder to directly modify return addresses, etc. on the stack, it's still possible to corrupt or maliciously attack such a program (if it's careless about buffer overflows).

Answer (score 3):

> can I say it prevents all the exploits of overflow?

No, global variables can overflow.

> if let's say I send this as the buffer to recv(int s, char *buf, int len,int flags); I will overwrite the data segment and may ruin the buf2 content, but I wouldn't be able to run a code from it. am I right? using Globals is the safest way?

No, the storage duration of a variable has no impact on whether or not it can be overflowed.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid buffer overflow is to avoid the use of static buffers and use libs like STL, boost etc for any objects that require memeory allocation eg use an STL vectors inplace of array.

Answer (score 2):

Buffer overrun vulnerabilities exist since a buffer on the stack is co-located with a return address farther along the stack.  Eventually the function must return and it uses that address to continue execution.  By purposely overwriting a buffer, one can deposit a different return address, perhaps to code that was deposited by the exploiter.

Certainly using global buffers reduces the chance of this specific type of exploit.  It does not, however, reduce the possibility of application failure as a result of damaging data outside the bounds of the current operation.

Global data has its downsides as well and it is not a comprehensive solution.  So the best approach would be to design your code defensively such that a buffer overrun simply cannot occur, regardless of where the buffer is located.

C and C++ both offer safe versions of buffer functions and these should be used along with good design as a primary guard against security exploits.